# General identity between genus 0 and genus 1 Virasoro conformal blocks?

Tags: conformal-field-theory

It was shown in https://arxiv.org/abs/0909.3412 that Virasoro conformal blocks associated to the four punctured sphere were related to Virasoro conformal blocks on the once-punctured torus.

Is it a coincidence? Is there any other relation between genus 0 and genus 1 Virasoro conformal blocks with a bigger number of punctures? I couldn't find on the literature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two objects underlying the coincidence are the Teichmuller space $\mathfrak{T}_{g,n}$ and the mapping class group $\Gamma_{g,n}$ of a Riemann surface with genus $g$ and $n$ punctures. Then for some values of $g$ and $n$, you can find coincidences, the most famous of which is 
$$\mathfrak{T}_{1,0}=\mathfrak{T}_{0,4}=\mathbb{H}$$
$$\Gamma_{1,0}=\Gamma_{0,4}=SL(2,\mathbb{Z})$$
where $\mathbb{H}$ is the upper-half plane of complex numbers with imaginary part $>0$.

You can read about this, e.g. in Gannon's book, *Moonshine beyond the Monster*, section 2.1.4.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I haven't thought about this. I could not find the reference yet, but is there any proof that if the Teichmüller space and the mapping class group of $\mathcal{C}_{g,n}$ and $\mathcal{C}_{g',n'}$ coincide, then the associated Virasoro conformal blocks are related to each other?

Comment: I don't know about a precise proof, but I think they should be related in some way. At least, the conformal blocks will depend on the same parameter (living in the quotient of the Teichmuller by the mapping class group), which you can relate with $q$ in the paper you cite. In other words, if the Teichmuller space and Mapping class group are not identical, the conformal blocks will depend on different parameters and I suspect there will not be such a simple relation between them.  

Take all this with a grain of salt, this is just my intuition and definitely not a precise answer.

Comment: The relation between Teichmüller spaces is certainly necessary for having a relation between conformal blocks, as it maps the geometric parameters: the modulus of the torus, and the cross-ratio of the sphere with four punctures. However, conformal blocks are not simple emanations of Riemannian geometry, and have more parameters: the conformal dimensions of the fields. The dimensions of the four fields on the sphere are all given in terms of the dimension of the one field on the torus (plus the central charge), in a way that is nontrivial and mysterious (to me).